# Custom Dialog that allows me to add to its list view and return the final list

Tags: android, android-listview, dialog

I have a custom dialog with a editview (where user puts an email address) and 'add' imageview  which when clicked should add the email to the listview and a list view which shows the list of email addresses.

I have 2 issues. Im not sure how add to the listview and update it on ui and secondly i cant seem to get my dialog to open at all. Anybody know the best way to do this?

Custom dialog xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'
    android:id='@+id/background'
    android:layout_width='fill_parent'
    android:layout_height='fill_parent'
    android:orientation='vertical'
    android:padding='10sp'
    android:background="@color/yellow">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText_email"
            android:hint="Enter player email address" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:id="@+id/imgView_add"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_create" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView_players"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn_confirm"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_confirm"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Iv tried dialog builder and regular dialog libs but hit small issues in both.

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);//remove the dialog title
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_inviteusers);
        dialog.setTitle("Sign In");


        //Hook up the dialog controls
        ImageView btn_add = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imgView_add);
        ListView listView_emails = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.listView_players);
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        Adapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, list);

        listView_emails.setAdapter((android.widget.ListAdapter) adapter);


        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do stuff

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
```

Comment: Why is the ListView in the dialog layout and not in the activity layout??

Comment: I want a dialog with a textview, clickable image that inserts editview text into listview, a list view that takes the input from editview and a clickable image button for confirm